# How to recover database from Mounting stage

Tags: marklogic, database, nosql

We are using MarkLogic server '7.0-2.3' which has couple of application database. On our 64 bit server, RAM is 16 GB, total available space is 368GB where 267 GB is freely available.

But still we are facing Mounting problem. From last 3 to 4 hr it is in Recovering mode. Is there any way which may help us to recover it faster without loosing any documents.

I already searched on WEB and find some solution on:

https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/134/0/my-forests-are-taking-a-long-time-to-mount---what-should-i-do

but I am unable to set those defined changes as MarkLogic is not responding.

[image: Image from MarkLogic server]

log error:

```
2015-03-23 11:22:26.795 Info: Mounted forest Last-Login locally on C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Forests\Last-Login read write
2015-03-23 11:22:26.826 Info: Mounted forest Documents locally on C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Forests\Documents read write
2015-03-23 11:22:26.841 Info: Mounted forest Modules locally on C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Forests\Modules read write
2015-03-23 11:22:26.873 Info: Mounted forest Extensions locally on C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Forests\Extensions read write
2015-03-23 11:22:26.904 Info: Mounted forest IETTV-Forest-RelatedContent locally on C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Forests\IETTV-Forest-RelatedContent read write
2015-03-23 11:22:26.904 Info: Mounted forest IETTV-Activity-Forest locally on C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Forests\IETTV-Activity-Forest read write
2015-03-23 11:22:26.935 Info: Mounted forest IETTV-Code-RelatedContent locally on C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Forests\IETTV-Code-RelatedContent read write
2015-03-23 11:22:26.935 Warning: Collapsing timestamps to 14272416000000000 for forest IETTV-Forest
2015-03-23 11:22:26.935 Warning: Missing journal file C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Forests\IETTV-Forest\Journals\Journal1-19861226230000-0-518119-0
2015-03-23 11:22:26.966 Info: Mounted forest Security locally on C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Forests\Security read write
2015-03-23 11:22:27.013 Warning: Collapsing timestamps to 14272416000000000 for forest IETTV-Activity-Forest
2015-03-23 11:22:27.013 Warning: Missing journal file C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Forests\IETTV-Activity-Forest\Journals\Journal1-19861226230000-0-138399-0
2015-03-23 11:25:00.824 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:26:00.629 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:27:00.229 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:28:00.709 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:28:30.852 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:29:00.850 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:30:00.844 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:31:00.855 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:32:00.855 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:33:00.870 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:34:00.890 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:35:00.902 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:36:01.027 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:37:00.028 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:38:00.034 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:39:00.040 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:40:00.057 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
2015-03-23 11:41:00.065 Error: PooledThread::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Meters not mounted: disconnected
```

Comment: Navin, are there any errors in ErrorLog.txt?

Comment: Dave, I have posted log file. I am able to take input of forest from 'Data' directory and install it on MarkLogic 8 another machine, data runs without any problem. But on same machine it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bad:

```
Warning: Missing journal file C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Forests\IETTV-Activity-Forest\Journals\Journal1-19861226230000-0-138399-0
```

That could be a result of filesystem corruption, possibly a bad disk or even bad memory. It's unlikely to be a bug in MarkLogic. So I'd check the OS logs to see if there are any relevant errors. I'd also run a full filesystem check.

You have backups, right?

You could contact support to see if they can help. They may recommend shutting down the server, then deleting the `Label` and `Journals` from that forest.

However if it's a low-level problem like filesystem corruption or a bad disk, you'll probably run into errors in other on-disk structures. In that case you're unlikely to recover the data. I predict you'll end up clearing the forest, after resolving whatever the low-level problem might be.

Finally — and this may have nothing to do with the problem — I'd upgrade to 7.0-5 to pick up the latest bug fixes: http://developer.marklogic.com/products/marklogic-server/7.0

Answer (score 0):

The "collapsing timestamps" messages suggest you've had a wildly incorrect date set for your host at some point in time.

The "disconnected" messages suggest either networking issues within your cluster, or that some of the machines are not running correctly.